# How can I resize 2 divs when hovering on another?

Tags: css

I have a project website. There are 3 divs. What I want to do is that when I hover on the first div, the other 2 get smaller for emphasis. I have tried this but only one of the 2 divs shrink using the sibling and parent divs. How can I resize to or more divs when hovering only one div?

I need in CSS because the rules says that javascript may not be used.

Comment: pls provide some example or code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to achieve this?

```css
.prnt2 {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  background: transparent;
}
.chld {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: lightgreen;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}
.prnt:hover .prnt2:not(:hover) .chld {
  height:50%;
  width: 50%;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}
.prnt2:hover .chld {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="prnt">
  <div class="prnt2">
    <div class="chld"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="prnt2">
    <div class="chld"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="prnt2">
    <div class="chld"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Banzay! I did work! But the problem is I can't change the background of each. Is there someway to achieve this? Can you teach me how it works and functions? I want to understand the code. :)

Comment: @AbdulAzisVedraPandi, I edited css to change background color on hover. And added some parent divs to make squares position and transition more stable.

Answer (score 0):

using the [sibling ~ selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_gen_sibling.asp) this can be achieved, Although its limited.

Here we're selecting all elements whith class .tohide that comes after divs with class .tohover, So as you can see they have come after the hovered element.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: orange;
  margin: 10px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.tohover:hover ~ .tohide {
  height:50px;
  vertical-align:top; /* To stick them to the top */
}
```

```html
<div class="tohover"></div>
<div class="tohide"></div>
<div class="tohide"></div>
```

Comment: It's pretty complicated but it works! Thank you! Can you tell me the function of .tohide and .tohover more? I want to know. Thank you!

Comment: Just go read the document about that selector and you'll understand